# Jframe equivalent for javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jframe

Hello I created a checkers game in Java using jframe and now I want to try in javascript to have it be a Web app. Does anyone know what the equivalent of jframe in javascript is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not really how js works. Any of the visual components which you would associate with something like swing would translate to HTML in this case. All the styling would be CSS, and then all the logic for how things interact would be written in javascript.

I suppose a jFrame would be like a div in HTML

Here's a short video if you need a [more robust explanation](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud248/l-1017018573/m-1013658596)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am just getting into javascript so I wanted to figure out the best way to approach things.

Comment: I get what you are saying that makes sense. I appreciate the video